# Why do power meters claim not to be usable for air conditioners?

Tags: mains, power-consumption

As the title says, why do some power meters (especially the ones readily around where I live) claim that they cannot be used with air conditioners and a few more devices?

One typical such device can be found [here](https://www.sanwa.co.jp/product/syohin?code=TAP-TST8N) (sorry, Japanese only).

In the bottom they say (rough translation)

> Do not use this device for appliances which are supposed to be directly connected to a wall outlet such as air conditioners, heaters, air conditioners, washing machines (...). If any of those appliances are used with this product, they could become hot or turn off due to poor connection.

What is the reasoning behind this warning? That the power meter is of poor quality and plugs will not fit well? Why are only a few products listed? Wouldn't pretty much any non-battery powered system turn off when the connection is poor and temporarily stops?

Originally I was thinking that the device cannot cope with large inductive loads, but the heaters are usually mostly resistive.

And now the most important question: How likely am I to damage my air conditioner if I use a power meter with such warning anyways?

Comment: Without knowing details of the innards of these particular power meters any answers are likely to be speculative guesses. It's not the general case that power meters are unable to be used with air conditioners (or any of the other listed appliances) - I have a power meter in my home which measures all of these without issues.

Comment: "Appliances which are supposed to be directly connected..." Sounds like appliances that draw large currents. Where I live, big, power-hungry appliances bear warning labels that say not to use an extension cord, and not to plug in to branch circuits that supply multiple outlets. Sounds like the manufacturer of the power meter wants to be able to say, "we told you not to do that" after you try to take them to court because their device caught fire.

Comment: They're probably covering their ass in case you plug a load with a huge start up current and burn out the device.

Comment: P.S., There are better power meters on the market. The instructions that came with mine _promise_ that I can safely plug any appliance in to it if the original plug on the appliance fits the outlet on the meter.

Comment: You already said it yourself by quoting the manual. If an appliance is supposed to be directly connected to an outlet, then by definition, there should be nothing between the outlet and appliance. So is not about your power meter. The power meter obviously does not pass earth/ground so it can't be used with earthed/grounded appliances.

Comment: @Justme ground connection is often/usually established via a separate cable. Note that this is in Japan, not US.

Comment: @Solomon Slow availability of known brands on other continents is often spotty. I tried, and it is... difficult.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's the inrush current. If I remember right most of of the power monitors for AC are only rated for 15 amps. Most wall mounted air conditioners can have the higher startup current more than 15amps, some up to 20amp.

Same goes for most relay switch smart plugs most only support up to 15 amp

Comment: Initially I thought the same, but they also list heaters. Those are mostly resistive. I do not expect a high inrush current there.